# How to first order by and the group by in mysql when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am joining three tables chat,users,messages and then grouping them using GROUP BY to get one data of similar rows and successfully i fired it. But now i want to order the messages by time. I have tried using order by time but didn't got result i want. The query i tried is -->

```
 SELECT
 m.*,c.*, s.uname as sender_name, r.uname as receiver_name,s.phone as
 sender_phone, r.phone as receiver_phone FROM message m
 JOIN chat c on c.mid = m.mid
 JOIN users s on s.uid = c.sender
 JOIN users r on r.uid = c.receiver
 WHERE c.sender = '1' or c.receiver = '1'
 group by IF(c.sender > c.receiver, c.sender,c.receiver),
          IF(c.sender > c.receiver, c.receiver,c.sender) 
 order by m.time
```

Comment: What result did you get, and what result did you want?

Comment: i got 1st message not the latest one between two friends. I want the latest message of chat between friends .

Comment: At first glance, you are ordering by time from oldest to newest. Try adding "DESC" at the end of your query. Sometimes when you are grouping by elements in one table, it's not as easy to order by elements in another table. You may need to break it into sub-queries.